# How to create date partitioned tables in GBQ? Can you use python?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I have just under 100M records of data that I wish to transform by denormalising a field and then input into a date partitioned GBQ table. The dates go back to 2001.

I had hoped that I could transform it with Python and then use GBQ directly from the script to accomplish this, but after reading up on this and particularly [this document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables) it doesn't seem straight-forward to create date-partitioned tables. I'm looking for a steer in the right direction.

Is there any working example of a python script that can do this? Or is it not possible to do via Python? Or is there another method someone can point me in the direction of?

**Update**

I'm not sure if I've missed something, but the tables created appear to be partitioned as per the insert date of when I'm creating the table and I want to partition by a date set within the existing dataset. I can't see anyway of changing this.

Here's what I've experimenting with:

```
import uuid
import os
import csv

from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud.bigquery import SchemaField
from google.cloud.bigquery import Client
from google.cloud.bigquery import Table
import logging #logging.warning(data_store+file)
import json
import pprint

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'path to service account credentials'

client = bigquery.Client()

dataset = client.dataset('test_dataset')
dataset.create()

SCHEMA = [
    SchemaField('full_name', 'STRING', mode='required'),
    SchemaField('age', 'INTEGER', mode='required'),
]
table = dataset.table('table_name', SCHEMA)
table.partitioning_type = "DAY"
table.create()

rows = [
    ('bob', 30),
    ('bill', 31)
]

table.insert_data(rows)
```

Is it possible to modify this to take control of the partitions as I create tables and insert data?

**Update 2**

It turns out I wasn't looking for table partitioning, for my use case it's enough to simply append a date serial to the end of my table name and then query with something along the lines of:

```
SELECT * FROM `dataset.test_dataset.table_name_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170701' AND '20170702'
```

I don't know whether this is technically still partitioning or not, but as far as I can see it has the same benefits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily create date partitioned tables using the API and Python SDK. Simply set the `timePartitioning` field to `DAY` in your script:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/a14905b6931ba3be94adac4d12d59232077b33d2/bigquery/google/cloud/bigquery/table.py#L219

Or roll your own table insert request with the following body:

```
{
  "tableReference": {
    "projectId": "myProject",
    "tableId": "table1",
    "datasetId": "mydataset"
  },
  "timePartitioning": {
    "type": "DAY"
  }
}
```

Everything is just backed by the REST api [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#timePartitioning).

Comment: Graham - I've not been able to take control of the partitions from what I've found from the sdk. I've explained more above. If you can advise at all that would be appreciated. Cheers

Comment: Ignore me - turns out I just don't know what I'm asking for. If I just append a date serial i.e 20170930 to the end of a table name for each date's data then I end up organising the data in the manner in which I'm able to query the tables using a star notation and _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN 'start' AND 'finish' - I take it now that this is not technically partitioning, they are actually separate tables, just with a convenient syntax with which to query them. Thanks again.

Comment: Do you have an example using the https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/usage.html in App Engine? I can't find anything and table_to_make = bigquery.Table(table_ref, partitioning_type = "DAY") does not work :)

Comment: Can someone let me know can I partition the table by YEAR.I was trying to partition the table by year . I know that there is currently only support for "type" : "DAY" in ```"timePartitioning"```.  I have also tried to partition using ```_PARTITIONTIME``` , but not successful in the attempt

Comment: @sarathgalimelu: Only day is supported currently.

Comment: Hey Graham, sorry to hitchhike this. but where exactly during the creation process would I specify the field I want to partition by?

Answer (score 6):

Updated to latest version (`google-cloud-biquery==1.4.0`)

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()
dataset_ref = client.dataset('test_dataset')
table_ref = dataset_ref.table('test_table')
SCHEMA = [
    SchemaField('full_name', 'STRING', mode='required'),
    SchemaField('age', 'INTEGER', mode='required'),
]
table = bigquery.Table(table_ref, schema=SCHEMA)

if partition not in ('DAY', ):
    raise NotImplementedError(f"BigQuery partition type unknown: {partition}")
table.time_partitioning = bigquery.table.TimePartitioning(type_=partition)
table = client.create_table(table)  # API request
```

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that different versions of `google-api-core` handle time-partitioned tables differently. For example, using `google-cloud-core==0.29.1`, you must use the `bigquery.Table` object to create time-partitioned tables:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

MY_SA_PATH = "/path/to/my/service-account-file.json"

MY_DATASET_NAME = "example"
MY_TABLE_NAME = "my_table"

client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(MY_SA_PATH)

dataset_ref = client.dataset(MY_DATASET_NAME)
table_ref = dataset_ref.table(MY_TABLE_NAME)

actual_table = bigquery.Table(table_ref)
actual_table.partitioning_type = "DAY"

client.create_table(actual_table)
```

I only discovered this by looking at the [0.20.1 Table source code](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/release-core-0.29.1/bigquery/google/cloud/bigquery/table.py). I didn't see this in any docs or examples. If you're having problems creating time-partitioned tables, I suggest that you identify the version of each Google library that you're using (for example, using `pip freeze`), and check your work against the library's source code.